# Stringbuilder to CSV

Tags: c#, csv, stringbuilder, streamwriter

I have the following Problem, I'm trying to get the Content from my StringBuilder to my .csv File:

```
public String GetCSV()
            {
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.Append(m_ID.ToString());
                sb.Append(";");
                sb.Append(m_Starttime.ToString());
                sb.Append(";");
                sb.Append(m_EndTime.ToString());
                sb.Append(";");
                sb.Append(m_IsSerie.ToString());
                sb.Append(";");
                sb.Append(m_Title);
                sb.Append(";");
                sb.Append(m_Description);
                sb.Append(";");
                sb.Append(m_Lastchange.ToString());
                sb.Append(";");

                return sb.ToString();
                WriteCSV();
            }


        public void WriteCSV()
        {                
            string csvpath = @"c:\Temp\Kalender.csv";

            if (File.Exists(csvpath))
            {
                File.Delete(csvpath);
            }

                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(csvpath))
                {
                    foreach (string CalendarItem in CalendarItem)
                    {
                        if (sb.Length > 0)
                            sb.Append(", ");

                        sb.Append(part);
                    }

                }

        }
```

Now I know how to create the CSV File already but I have no idea how I could fill it with my Content from the StringBuilder
I'm sure that'll be handled by an foreach Loop right?

Comment: is your CSV just the one line? Also, code after the `return` won't be executed.

Comment: Your code seems quite broken, WriteCSV will never be called. Anyway, after your loop, you simply need to write `sw.Write(sb.ToString())`

Comment: thanks @Rob 
@.Jonesy jup that was just a beginners fault ;) 
@.PatrickHofman the last 3 rows aren't mine, I was checking something but didn't worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `StringBuilder AppendLine` to create new line and than write the complete `StringBuilder` to the file-system with [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx). Take a look at [AppendLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also,  `WriteCSV();` will never be executed, because you have a `return` before.